# Search API Solr sorting with Entityqueue

Tags: views, search, 9

i have a Drupal search api view with solr.

I want to use entity queue for sorting the view and setting a specific order of nodes.
However this does not work at all.

I have added the relation with entity queue and also added the fields to the sorting part of the view. Nothing seems to change the sorting.
Does anyone knows how i can fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not supported out of the box, see https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/3016821 for the outline of an approach you can use to implement it

Comment: Thanks @Clive, with the custom processor i managed to sort by entity queue :)